# Negamax A/B pruning rate. Move ordering

Tags: minimax

I have a typical negamax with a/b pruning setup and thoroughly checked line by line. What is expected cutoff rate normally? Kind of surprisingly, in my case cutoff rate is rarely greater than 5%. Is it as it should be? What is interesting is that regardless of any move sorting I am applying the rate is still between 3-5%. What is average cutoff rate I should expect?

What I tried is this:

1. No move ordering (sorting)
2. Capturing moves first
3. Capturing moves first and then use "heat" map (adding a small value to moves that put the piece to a better position, like using maps where for each type of piece positions are weighted)
4. Went as far as during the move sorting I did the following: for each found move make the move, evaluate the board outcome (pieces under attack, pieces under defence, total material evaluation) and use the outcome for move ordering.

In all those scenarios I keep getting the cutoff rate no more that 6%. Once again, I have checked the implementation of negamax with a/b pruning line by line, and I believe board evaluation is correct.

Comment: What depth are you searching to? If it's just something like 2 ply this might be normal but otherwise your entire AB thing is probably not working correctly.